# Login api that checks UserName and Password and let user sees his information using swift and asp.net web api

Tags: ios, asp.net, web-services, http, asp.net-web-api

I am new to iOS development.

I have created Web Api based on Asp.NET and it is hosted in Azure web server.

My model looks like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public decimal Rebate { get; set; }
    public decimal MemCom { get; set; }
}
```

And GET, POST, PUT, DELETE all working fine in my server
(You can test it because I didn't set any security)
`http://tresmorewebapi2.azurewebsites.net/help`

And this is my `AccountsConroller`:

```
namespace TresmoreWebApi.Controllers {

    public class AccountsController: ApiController {
        private TresmoreWebApiContext db = new TresmoreWebApiContext();

        // GET: api/Accounts
        public IQueryable < Account > GetAccounts() {
            return db.Accounts;
        }

        // GET: api/Accounts/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Account))]
        [Route("api/account/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAccount(int id) {
            Account account = db.Accounts.Find(id);
            if (account == null) {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(account);
        }

        // PUT: api/Accounts/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutAccount(int id, Account account) {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != account.Id) {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try {
                db.SaveChanges();
            } catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) {
                if (!AccountExists(id)) {
                    return NotFound();
                } else {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/Accounts
        [ResponseType(typeof(Account))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostAccount(Account account) {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Accounts.Add(account);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = account.Id }, account);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Accounts/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Account))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteAccount(int id) {
            Account account = db.Accounts.Find(id);
            if (account == null) {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Accounts.Remove(account);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(account);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing) {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool AccountExists(int id) {
            return db.Accounts.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And below is my GET & POST request functions in Swift Xcode:

```
//GET
@IBAction func pressedGet(_ sender: Any) {
    let restEndPoinst: String = "http://tresmorewebapi2.azurewebsites.net/api/accounts"
    guard let url = URL(string: restEndPoinst) else {
        print("Error creating URL")
        return
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // api key need urlRequest.setValue(<#T##value: String?##String?#>, forHTTPHeaderField: "APIKey")
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:
        {
            (data, response, error) in
            print("Error:")
            print(error)
            print("response:")
            print(response)
            print("Data:")
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
    })

    task.resume()
}

//POST
@IBAction func pressedPost(_ sender: Any) {
    let restEndPoinst: String = "http://tresmorewebapi2.azurewebsites.net/api/accounts"
    guard let url = URL(string: restEndPoinst) else {
        print("Error creating URL")
        return
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // api key need urlRequest.setValue(<#T##value: String?##String?#>, forHTTPHeaderField: "APIKey")


    let jsonDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    //jsonDictionary.setValue(9, forKey: "Id")
    jsonDictionary.setValue("iostest", forKey: "UserName")
    jsonDictionary.setValue("iospassword", forKey: "UserPassword")
    jsonDictionary.setValue("ios@gmail.com", forKey: "UserEmail")
    jsonDictionary.setValue(200.44, forKey: "Rebate")
    jsonDictionary.setValue(1200.20, forKey: "MemCom")

    let jsonData: Data
    do{
        jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDictionary, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
        urlRequest.httpBody = jsonData
    }
    catch{
        print("Error creating JSON")
        return
    }

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:
        {
            (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            print("Error:")
            print(error)
            print("response:")
            print(response)
            print("Data:")
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

When I do GET request I get this output in Xcode:
I get 200 http resoponse and this output

Data:

> Optional("[{\"Id\":1,\"UserName\":\"codeinflash\",\"UserPassword\":\"Wldnrodxxxx\",\"UserEmail\":\"codeinflash@gmail.com\",\"Rebate\":0.00,\"MemCom\":123.44},{\"Id\":2,\"UserName\":\"iostest\",\"UserPassword\":\"iospassword\",\"UserEmail\":\"ios@gmail.com\",\"Rebate\":200.44,\"MemCom\":1200.20}]")

I am sorry long codes above..

How do I make a simple login web api & swift function that checks user's input from iOS textfield and returns his email address from db..??

I think login is POST request (I am not sure)

and below is how far I got making login function in swift:

```
//POST Login
@IBAction func LoginBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let _userName = UserName.text
    let _userPassword = UserPassword.text
    //alert if loginid or password is empty
    if (_userName!.isEmpty) || (_userPassword!.isEmpty){
        createAlert(title: "Warning", message: "Login ID or Password is invalid input")
        return
    }

    //LogIn uses POST method
    let restEndPoinst: String = "http://tresmorewebapi2.azurewebsites.net/api/accounts"
    guard let url = URL(string: restEndPoinst) else {
        print("Error creating URL")
        return
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // api key need urlRequest.setValue(<#T##value: String?##String?#>, forHTTPHeaderField: "APIKey")

    //need logic here so after approved the user can see his email address in iOS
    //
    //

}
```

Thank you!

**This is POST method in my asp.net web api**

```
//Login
    // POST: api/Accounts/Login
    [ResponseType(typeof(Account))]
    [Route("api/accounts/login")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostLogin(string userName, string userPassword)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        //Account account = db.Accounts.Find(userName, userPassword);
        Account account = db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserName == userName && c.UserPassword == userPassword);
        int id;
        if (account == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            id = account.Id;
            Console.WriteLine(account.UserEmail + " " + id);
        }
        return Ok(id);
    }
```

Comment: are you using default identity providers for web api or you choose an empty template ? I mean did you created it from scratch ?

Comment: @JawandSingh I started from empty template. I created it from scratch.

Comment: are you planning to use identity providers ? basically you have to use token based authentication in web api.

Comment: well this [link](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/) is one of the fine article on how to implement identity and token based auth in web api from scratch. please let me know if you are looking for something else

Comment: @JawandSingh before using token based authenticatoin.. is there no way to implement my situation?? I added action `PostLogin` codes up there.

Comment: what i understood is that you want user to login and then user can view the `Account` Model information in his/her profile. right ?

Comment: @JawandSingh Yes that is correct. Simply I want to let users input their usename & password using POST request from swift ant my asp.net web api returns his/her account information.

Comment: so, tell me you want to use identity in your web api, i.e. default authentication for web api with user roles and auto generated tables for it .

Comment: @JawandSingh I thought creating web api from scratch will help me a lot.. I know if I choose authentication template it automatically creates for me.. but I wanted to understand how HTTP works between Swift. Now GET, POST, PUT, DELETE http requests all working.. but I don't know how to implement login feature to my web api..

Comment: well when you try things you learn, i will suggest you to create web api with authentication and then you have database tables generated and i will also suggest you to use database first approach for database and you will have an endpoint `http://localhost:4005/token` to let user login (technically it will return a token which mobile app have to use to make request to api) this request will be `x-form-urlencoded` and not `application/json` and you need to pass username and password. Hope this helps you.

Comment: @JawandSingh so you are saying I should create a new project in visual studio and choose asp.net web api with authentication template?
OK I will do that. But is there any way to implement my login action up there I added? Please take a look my action `PostLogin`. Thanks!!

Comment: yes you need to create a new project, and the code you have added for login is wrong way of doing it, by looking at the code above it seems like passwords are not hashed in databases. I'll share a piece of code which can be used as login method, and it will be using default authentication by Microsoft and which is pretty decent.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code which will act as login method in Web API

```
// POST api/Account/login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("login")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> LoginUser(LoginUserBindingModel model)
{
     if (model == null)
     {
         return this.BadRequest("Invalid user data");
     }
     // Invoke the "token" OWIN service to perform the login (POST /api/token)
     var testServer = TestServer.Create<Startup>();
     var requestParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
     {
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", model.Username),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", model.Password)
     };

     var requestParamsFormUrlEncoded = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams);
     var tokenServiceResponse = await testServer.HttpClient.PostAsync(
     "/api/Token", requestParamsFormUrlEncoded);
     return this.ResponseMessage(tokenServiceResponse);
}
```

your model class for login

```
public class LoginUserBindingModel
{
   [Required]
   public string Username { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [DataType(DataType.Password)]
   public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I am assuming you will be using default template from asp.net web api with authentication. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try again from ground with authentication template at beginning.